# SharePoint 2010 Modal Window - Detect when content has fully loaded

Tags: 2010, javascript, modal-dialog

I have a SP 2010 page, where I have several links that open modal windows with the following code:

```
function OpenModalPage(url, title) {
var myModalPageOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    myModalPageOptions.url = url;
    myModalPageOptions.title = title;
    myModalPageOptions.allowMaximize = true;
    myModalPageOptions.showClose = true;
    myModalPageOptions.width = 600;
    myModalPageOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, silentCallbackModalDialog);
return SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(myModalPageOptions);
}
function silentCallbackModalDialog(dialogResult, returnValue) {}
```

I'm looking to call this function from another event as opposed to clicking. This isn't hard, but what I need to is "check" when the content has loaded.

Is there a function or property I can check in `SP.UI.ModalDialog` or `SP.UI.Dialog` that gets set to true once the content has loaded?

The other idea I have is to check the HTML content of everything that is loaded in the modal, and when I have HTML content, then its loaded. But I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I went through a bunch of [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee552096(v=office.14).aspx) but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Why you want to find DialogLoaded from the parent?

Comment: I'm using a tool similar to Intro.JS to showcase information on a page. Some of that information is in a modal window. So, I need to call a function, load some data (in this case, the HTML for the modal window), then when everything is loaded use Intro.JS to attach a tool-tip to some elements within the modal.

Comment: Dialog should be targeted to a particular page. Why can't you put this logic in that page?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. Do you mean set some global variable in JS on the source of the modal window, then check if that variable is true / set?

Comment: no `myModalPageOptions.url = url;` here you are assigning a URL. Open that page and put the JavaScript logic for tooltip in that page.

Comment: That won't work because I want to tooltip to live outside of the iframe. Also, it'll be easier to develop since I only have to work within one page instead of adding "callbacks" to each iframe I'm going to open. I was able to find another solution, which I posted below. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to use the code below

```
var intervalDialogue = setInterval(function () {
    var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
    if (dialog != null && dialog.$e_0 != null) {
        clearInterval(intervalDialogue);
    }
    else {
        console.log("waiting for popup to load");
    }
},500);
```

This will look for the changes in the HTML of the opened modal box and as soon as the HTML(`dialog.$e_0`) is available, the contents are loaded for the modal.

Comment: For SP 2016 answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275286/detect-when-modal-window-is-fully-loaded

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this but check the HTML of the iframe. This was my initial idea, and although it isn't ideal and seems to have a fair amount of overhead for a simple check, it is working for me.

```
function OpenModalPage(url, title) {
  var myModalPageOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
      myModalPageOptions.url = url;
      myModalPageOptions.title = title;
      myModalPageOptions.allowMaximize = true;
      myModalPageOptions.showClose = true;
      myModalPageOptions.width = 600;
      myModalPageOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, silentCallbackModalDialog);
  return SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(myModalPageOptions);
}
function silentCallbackModalDialog(dialogResult, returnValue) {}


function OpenModalAndCallWhenLoaded(url, title, callback) {
  var modal = OpenModalPage(url, title);

  var contentLoadedTimeout = setTimeout(function(){console.log("contentLoaded TimeOut");clearInterval(contentLoaded);},20000);
  var contentLoaded = setInterval(function() {
    var $modal = $(modal.get_frameElement());
    if ($modal.contents().find("form[action='"+modal.get_url()+"?IsDlg=1']").length) {
      clearInterval(contentLoaded);
      clearTimeout(contentLoadedTimeout);
      callback();
      return true;
    };
  }, 100);
}

function itIsLoaded() {
  console.log("It worked!");
  //Do other stuff here
}

OpenModalAndCallWhenLoaded('/my/page/index.aspx', 'My Sample Page', itIsLoaded);
```