# Detect when modal window is fully loaded

Tags: 2016, sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

I'm using this piece of code (based on solution [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/218964/33924)) to check whether modal window fully loaded:

```
var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
if (dialog != null && dialog.$e_0 != null) {
    clearInterval(intervalDialogue);
}
```

This works perfectly in SP 2013 but in SP 2016 `dialog.$e_0` is always undefined. Is there an alternative for SP 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `dialog.$e_0` to `dialog.$i_0` and now it's working fine.